# When placing bypass capacitors on the back side of a PCB to support a large BGA part can I share the same VIA?

Tags: pcb-design

Here is what I am wondering. Is the example PCB layout fine for handling bypass capacitors? Or, do I need to run a separate VIA as well? Note that the blue caps are on the backside of the PCB.

Also, I understand that this layout is incomplete, I'm just curious about the shared via. :-)

[image]

Comment: Should be listed in the application note. Having one via to two capacitors will have approximately twice the inductance compared to two vias. In general, the BGA pitch will determine the minimum via size and pad-to-via distance needed (and to some extent if you need buried and blind vias), which in the end should allow you to place as many vias as needed, even if that's one per pin.

Comment: Why do you think you need two separate caps on that one Vcc pad?  It's not like you're hurting for Vcc (or GND) pads on a big part like that.

Comment: I'm thinking both N8 and N7 need a separate cap

Comment: If you can fit a 2nd via, do it. If not, try to make the via diameter larger. If you can't even do that, then you're stuck with what you've got (assuming you can't pay for via-in-pad). If you don't have any power integrity simulation tool you're stuck just doing the best you can and hoping for success. Whether that's good enough depends how clever you are and how good the chip designers and the app notes from the chip vendor are.

Comment: What frequencies is involved, or what power delivery network impedance the BGA device requires?